# Vim Round floats to one decimal place

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm setting up a function in my .vimrc (using MacVim in particular, but this should be universal to vim in general) to display file sizes (in Bytes, Kilobytes, and Megabytes) in my statusline. While the function works quite perfectly without errors, it's giving me unexpected output! In hindsight, it's certainly producing the output it should, but not the output I want.

Here's the function:

```vim
" I modified the FileSize() function shown here to suit my own preferences:
" http://got-ravings.blogspot.com/2008/08/vim-pr0n-making-statuslines-that-own.htm
function! StatuslineFileSize()
    let bytes = getfsize(expand("%:p"))
    if bytes < 1024
        return bytes . "B"
    elseif (bytes >= 1024) && (bytes < 10240)
        return string(bytes / 1024.0) . "K"
    elseif (bytes >= 10240) && (bytes < 1048576)
        return string(bytes / 1024) . "K"
    elseif (bytes >= 1048576) && (bytes < 10485760)
        return string(bytes / 1048576.0) . "M"
    elseif bytes >= 10485760
        return string(bytes / 1048576) . "M"
    endif
endfunction
```

Here's the way it basically works:

1. If filesize is less than 1KB, output size in Bytes as an integer
2. If filesize is between 1KB and 10KB, output size in Kilobytes as a decimal
3. If filesize is between 10KB and 1MB, output size in Kilobites as an integer
4. If filesize is between 1MB and 10MB, output size in Megabytes as a decimal
5. If filesize is greater than 10MB, output size in Megabytes as an integer

The output produced for steps 2 and 4 are decimals with *six* (6) places of precision. The desired output I would like to have should be decimals with just **one** (1) place of precision.

I've already searched help documentation for the `round()` and `trunc()` functions, but they will only round and truncate floats to the nearest whole number value, which is not what I would like to have happen. I've also searched the Google and StackOverflow for solutions, but most of what I can find involves altering text in the edit buffer or completely unrelated problems such as rounding floats in Java (!!!)

I'm preferably looking for a vim built-in function that can do this, a la `round({expr},{prec})` or `trunc({expr},{prec})`, but if a user defined function can provide a sufficiently elegant solution then I'm all for that as well. I don't mind if the output is a string, since I'm obviously returning a string from `StatuslineFileSize()` anyways!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `printf` with precision specifiers to convert the results to strings instead of `string`:

```
return printf('%.1fM', bytes / 1048576)
```

Comment: Derrrp! I can't believe I totally forgot to search for `printf()`! This is EXACTLY what I needed! Thanks a ton! :D